# How to override a CSS rule for a class whose data-attribute value matches with that of an anchor tag?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, frontend

I'm trying to add **read more** links to different sections of a WordPress page, that when clicked is expected to display the contents hidden with CSS by default. Below are a couple of sections in the HTML format. I need to create multiple similar sections.

Section 1:

```
<p>What kinds of gifts should you give employees? <a class="more-link-pwp" href="#" data-more-link-id="1">Read More.</a></p>
<div class="more-content-pwp" data-more-content-id="1">How much should you spend? Should corporate gifts for employees be company-branded? Our expert team will help you choose memorable, unique gifts for your employees and office staff.</div>
```

Section 2:

```
<p> Deepen employee engagement and impress new hires while giving employee gifts that are meaningful and memorable. <a class="more-link-pwp" href="#" data-more-link-id="2">Read More.</a></p>
<div class="more-content-pwp" data-more-content-id="2">From empowering underserved women with job skills to supporting sustainability efforts every gift creates an impact. Our Impact Booklet showcases these inspiring stories, providing a unique experience for gift recipients.</div>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
```

Since both the sections use same classes, I added data-more-link-id="1" and data-more-content-id="1" to each section to target a specific section. The jQuery code I wrote is below, which is wrong somewhere. Could you please help me fix it?

```
$('.more-link-pwp').click(function() {
  // get data-more-link-id
  var dataMorelinkid = $(this).attr("data-more-link-id");
  // get data-more-content-id 
  var dataMorecontentid = = $(.more-content-pwp).attr("data-more-content-id");
 
  // Iterate through dataMorecontentid.
  for (let i = 0; i < dataMorecontentid.length; i++) {
   if (dataMorecontentid[i] == dataMorelinkid) {
   // Change CSS for the classes whose data-more-content-id matches data-more-link-id.
      $('.more-content-pwp').css('display', 'block');
      $(this).css('display', 'none');
      return false;
   }
});
```

CSS: `.more-content-pwp {display: none;}`

What I'm trying to achieve is whenever a read more link is clicked, only the hidden content specific to that more link should be displayed, not the contents from other sections that use the same class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$('.more-link-pwp').click(function() {
  // get data-more-link-id
  var dataMorelinkid = $(this).attr("data-more-link-id");

  $(this).hide(); // update 1
  $(".more-content-pwp").each(function(){
     // $(this).hide(); // update 2
      const id = $(this).attr('data-more-content-id');
      if(id == dataMorelinkid){
      $(this).show();
      }
  });  
  
  });
```

```css
.more-content-pwp{
display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>What kinds of gifts should you give employees? <a class="more-link-pwp" href="#" data-more-link-id="1">Read More.</a></p>
<div class="more-content-pwp" data-more-content-id="1">How much should you spend? Should corporate gifts for employees be company-branded? Our expert team will help you choose memorable, unique gifts for your employees and office staff.</div>

<p> Deepen employee engagement and impress new hires while giving employee gifts that are meaningful and memorable. <a class="more-link-pwp" href="#" data-more-link-id="2">Read More.</a></p>
<div class="more-content-pwp" data-more-content-id="2">From empowering underserved women with job skills to supporting sustainability efforts every gift creates an impact. Our Impact Booklet showcases these inspiring stories, providing a unique experience for gift recipients.</div>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
```

The below line will output a string not an array.

```
var dataMorecontentid = = $(.more-content-pwp).attr("data-more-content-id");
```

The below code works.

Comment: Alaksandar, thanks. I need the Read More button to disappear once it is clicked and the hidden content is displayed.

Comment: This is the page where I applied your solution, and it appears to need a bit more work to be perfect. https://dev-packed-with-purpose.pantheonsite.io/corporate-gifts/employee-gifts/

Comment: Once displayed how do you hide it then

Comment: Using CSS as in my post. This line $(this).css('display', 'none');

Comment: $(this).hide(); // update 1 will hide the Read More Link. Also use href="javascript:void(0)" instead of # so your page does not scroll up on click

Comment: It works almost perfect. One last thing is that the once you click the second Read more after clicking the first read more link, the first read more link as well as the hidden content display. Please have a look at the page now to see it happen.

Comment: I did not understand the above comment. But i assume, you want the content to be visible once opened. You need to comment out this line. // $(this).hide(); // update 2

Comment: Perfect, it works now. Thanks a lot for your time and efforts.

Comment: Sorry to bother you again, Alaksandar. I applied the solution on the live page now, but I get this error on the page. Uncaught TypeError: $ is not a function. I copied the solution as is. The page is https://packedwithpurpose.gifts/corporate-gifts/employee-gifts/. Kindly have a look

Comment: try jQuery instead of $... it depends on how you have initialized jQuery.... Remember it is case sensitive. So stick to jQuery

Comment: Yes, it worked. But can assign jQuery to $ and then use $ every where?

Comment: Yes. But dont do that.. jQuery is used as in no conflict situation, preferrably in php coding.  https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_noconflict.asp  .. Instead of $ use jQuery for wp project

Comment: Okay, I replaced $ with jQuery at 4 places in the code you wrote for me. Thanks

Comment: Alaksandra, could you please have a look at the post on trouble reading active element? Link to it is here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73364211/hide-open-active-accordion-when-another-accordion-is-clicked